# Bash while if function

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm try to run this bash script.

```
#!/bin/sh

MAX=5

j=1 

while [ $((1+$j)) -le $MAX ] do 

input=$j

if [ $input -le $j ] then 
echo "input=$j,$j,$((j+1)),$((j+2)),$((j+3)),$((j+4))" 
else 
echo "$input" 
fi j=$((j+1))

done
```

I am writing a bash script and trying to check the order list provided in the argument of the shell values. The ouput has the content as:

```
 input=1,1,2,3,4,5 
 input=2,2,3,4,5,6 
 input=3,3,4,5,6,7 
 input=4,4,5,6,7,8
```

As what I expect it should give the list in increase order at the each line but the result that i'm looking for is:

```
 input=1,2,3,4,5 
 input=2,1,3,4,5 
 input=3,1,2,4,5 
 input=4,1,2,3,5
 input=5,1,2,3,4
```

Please help me, thanks.

Comment: so basically, whatever $j is, strip it from the list for that line?

Comment: Where are you capping the value of `j` in this code? So that it stops at `5` instead of counting past that. Where are you subtracting from `j` so that you can get `3,1,` etc.? Are you just trying to output permutations of the numbers one through five? What is your *actual* goal here?

Comment: i'm trying to ouput  permutations of the numbers 1 to 5. If the number exits in input, print the others numbers in list whitout the number read in input.

Comment: Just run the code in your head. Obviously if you have `input=$j,$j,...` you're going to get your number repeating twice at the beginning of the string. Also `input=$j; if [ $input -le $j ] then ...` is a useless check; you've just done the assignment, they'll always be equal.

Comment: Note that you need a semicolon or newline before the `do` in your loop; also before the `then` in your `if` condition.  The line `fi j=$((j+1))` is invalid too; put the two parts on separate lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script, when you are iterating on variable `j`, only the while loop is keeping track of the range {1 .. MAX}. Hence, if you are at `j=5` in your loop, then running `echo` on `$j,$((j+1)),$((j+2)),$((j+3)),$((j+4))` results `5,6,7,8,9` respectively, which is not what you are looking for.

One approach at a solution is, given a number `i`, creating a range {1 .. MAX} with `i` removed. For example, given `i=2`, creating the list `1,3,4,...,MAX`. This can then be concatenated to the final output format as `echo "input=$i,$list"`.

The following `range` routine creates such a list:

```
# range() outputs a range of numbers 1 to MAX, but with
#    the number 'num' removed from the range.
# Usage: range num MAX
# Example: [ input: range 2 5 ] [ output: 1,3,4,5 ]
range() {
    num="$1"
    MAX="$2"
    for i in $(eval echo {1..$MAX}); do
        if [ "$num" -eq "$MAX" ]; then
            if [ "$i" -eq $((MAX-1)) ]; then
                printf "$i"
                break
            else
                printf "$i,"
            fi
        elif [ "$i" -eq "$MAX" ]; then
            printf "$i"
        elif [ "$i" -eq "$num" ]; then
            continue
        else
            printf "$i,"
        fi
    done
    printf "\n"
}
```

Then your while loop becomes,

```
j=1
MAX=5

while [ "$j" -le "$MAX" ]; do
    list=$(range "$j" "$MAX")
    echo "input=$j,$list"
    j=$((j+1))
done
```

whereby `list` variable is assigned the values of the range created with `range "$j" "$MAX"`, then `list` is concatenated to final output.

---

**Tests:** Assuming the above script is named `permute`,

```
# when j=1 and MAX=5
$ ./permute
input=1,2,3,4,5
input=2,1,3,4,5
input=3,1,2,4,5
input=4,1,2,3,5
input=5,1,2,3,4

# when j=1 and MAX=10
$ ./permute
input=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
input=2,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
input=3,1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
input=4,1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10
input=5,1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10
input=6,1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10
input=7,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10
input=8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10
input=9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10
input=10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```